# How to fixed 400 Bad Request of my web API Call in my window service app

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, windows-services, httpclient

I made an auto scheduler where data is forwarded to my AWS Server.
I created a Window Service that runs every min to forward the new data.
I have an existing API that received the data in AWS Server.

> Window Service works fine with API on network server
>
> API Address1 : http:\\192.168.0.1\api\data\getdata (Working in network 100%)
>
> API Address2 : https:\\api.mydomain.com\api\data\getdata (Tested in winform and postman
>   working 100%)
>
> But encountered a problem when window services send data to API Address 2

Here is the code

```
public static void SendData()
{
    var PostData = new Profile
    {
        ID = 99,
        Code = "123",
        Email = 'xyz@yahoo.com'
    };

    try
    {

        var PostBody = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(PostData);
        var PostContent = new StringContent(PostBody, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        //BaseAddress = "https:\\api.mydomain.com";

        using (var Client = API_Client.GetClient("api/data/getdata"))
        {
            var Sending = Client.PostAsync(Client.BaseAddress.ToString(), PostContent);

            Sending.Wait();

            var Response = Sending.Result;

            if (Response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                Logger.WriteLine("Sending Info to API '" + PostData.ID.ToString() + "'", "Success");
            }
            else
            {
                Logger.WriteLine("Sending Info to API '" + PostData.ID.ToString() + "'", Response.ReasonPhrase);
            }
        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Logger.WriteLine("Error '" + PostData.ID.ToString()  + "' To Server", ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Here is Error Message

```
{StatusCode: 400, ReasonPhrase: 'Bad Request', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  Pragma: no-cache
  Connection: close
  Cache-Control: no-cache
  Date: Thu, 13 Dec 2018 06:40:34 GMT
  Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
  X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
  X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
  Content-Length: 41
  Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
  Expires: -1
}}
```

API Client Helper

```
public class API_Client
{

    protected static string API_BASE_ADDRESS = "https:\\api.mydomain.com\";

    public static HttpClient GetClient(string URL_Target)
    {

        var Client = new HttpClient()
        {
            BaseAddress = new Uri(API_BASE_ADDRESS + URL_Target),
            Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 90)
        };

        Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.ConnectionClose = true;

        return Client;
    }

}
```

Postman
[image]

Comment: shouldnt "API_Client.GetClient("api/data/getdata")" take baseurl ("https:\\api.mydomain.com") and Client.PostAsync the route "api/data/getdata"?

Comment: Based Address was constructed in API_Client helper..

Comment: Can you add the result headers from the Postman triggered request?

Comment: cache-control →no-cache
content-length →29
content-type →application/json; charset=utf-8
date →Thu, 13 Dec 2018 08:44:29 GMT
expires →-1
pragma →no-cache
server →Microsoft-IIS/8.5
x-aspnet-version →4.0.30319
x-powered-by →ASP.NET